# Rmarkdown insert degree symbol inside of a table

Tags: r, r-markdown, symbols

I'm trying to create a table in Rmarkdown that includes latitude and longitudes with the degree symbol. I'm familiar with using `expression()` and paste to get the degree into axis labels, for example, but when I try to create the data.frame for my table with `expression()` it doesn't like that. Alternatively, if I try a more markdown specific approach like `&deg`, I can not get that to work inside of the table using `paste("58",&deg,"22.00'")`.

I have been trying to make the table using `kable` or `xtable` but I'm happy with alternative suggestions.

Certainly, using decimal coordinates for lat/long would be a solution but not really the one I am looking for.

I've read several posts that are similar but none that are trying to include the symbol inside of a table.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to replicate. Thank you!!!

[image]

Comment: Are you knitting to PDF or HTML?

Comment: @alistaire Knitting to pdf

Comment: Add `\usepackage{gensymb}` to your YAML then use `\\degree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment: just paste `\\degree` anywhere you want the degree sign to pop up and add `\usepackage{gensymb}` to your preamble.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{gensymb}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars, col.names = paste0(names(mtcars), '\\degree'))
```
````

[image]